# nodejs get request is blocking loadtest, needed non blocking

Tags: node.js

I am trying to re-request another webaddress after i get nodejs route.

so

```
route('/get')

request('google.com.')
res.end(200)
```

When I try load testing with this code. App cannot process requests concurrently.

How can I resolve this to run paralel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parallelize it and wait for everything to return before calling `end`, you can use Promise.all.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```